# c pointer in MPI

Tags: c, mpi

I mpi program like this:

```
........
MPI_Status status1;

.......
MPI_Recv(rb,buf_size,MPI_INT,prcid,1,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status1);

.....
```

this program can run well. 
but when i change it like this:

```
........
MPI_Status* status2;

.......
MPI_Recv(rb,buf_size,MPI_INT,prcid,1,MPI_COMM_WORLD,status2);

.....
```

it can't run well and gets an error:

```
erro: Segmentation fault (signal 11)
```

Doesn't  `&status1` equal `status2`?

what is the difference between them ? 
thank you !

Comment: did you initialize the pointer variable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, they are not equivalent, although you are certainly passing the same **type** of argument each time, which is why the compiler does not complain.

In one case you are passing the address of a structure already  allocated on the stack.

In the other case you are passing a pointer which is pointing at some arbitrary (probably non-writeable) location in memory, because it is not initialized.

You can fix the second call with `malloc` to allocate memory and point the pointer at it.

```
MPI_Status* status2 = malloc(sizeof(MPI_Status));
```

Of course, after you are done with it, you should be responsible and `free()` that memory:

```
free(status2);
```

Answer (score 5):

In the first case, `status1` is an object, so `&status1` is a pointer to a valid object which `MPI_Recv` can write to.

In the second case, `status2` is an uninitialized pointer.  Its value is probably some random stack garbage, so when `MPI_Recv` tries to write to it, it writes to some random memory location.  A lot of memory doesn't like being written to, so you get a segfault.  You could also get some subtle memory corruption that will cause strange problems later on.

If you try this, it should work:

```
MPI_Status status1;
MPI_Status* status2 = &status1;

.......
MPI_Recv(rb,buf_size,MPI_INT,prcid,1,MPI_COMM_WORLD,status2);
```